# How to (reset || restart || clear) form2 in WPF in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, application-restart

> My application is consist of two forms.

```
Form1 and Form2
```

Currently I'm facing problem in form2. The problem is that i want to restart my form2. To restart my form2 i'm using

```
application.restart();
```

But this restart whole project and form1 appears again.

> My question is that is there any way so i could able to restart my
>   only form2 not whole application.

Below is the simple code for explanation.

```
private void btn_restart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {
                Application.Restart(); //Restart whole project :(


            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this restart whole project and form1 appears again.

Yes, it is expected as the method `Restart` is getting on `Application` class and that's sole purpose is to restart whole application.

You can use the `Close()` to  programmatically invoke the close window action and then you can create new instance of your Form like:

```
private void btn_restart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  form2.Close();  // close it
  form2 = new Form2(); // reopen it
  form2.Show(); // show on the screen

}
```

If you `Form2` expects parameters in constructor, then you of-course would need to pass those, assuming that it has parameter-less constructor while answering this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: these are  framework provided method, do you see any compile time erros, what you mean by not working?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Can you show us the code where you open the form?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It isn't working as soon as i click restart button the from2 blinks and form1 reappears.

Comment: I only want to restart the form2 like if i click restart button only form2 restart not form1.

Comment: the above code should do that can you show  your form1 and form1 code behind by updating your  question